# python - test that class has been instantiated with arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, mocking, python-unittest

I'm pretty new with python, and I'm trying to figure out how to test this code.

Here is my class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
from generator import *

parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='XOS Generative Toolchain')
parse.add_argument('--rev', dest='rev', action='store_true',default=False, help='Convert proto to xproto')
parse.add_argument('--target', dest='target', action='store',default=None, help='Output format, corresponding to <output>.yaml file', required=True)
parse.add_argument('--output', dest='output', action='store',default=None, help='Destination dir', required=True)
parse.add_argument('--attic', dest='attic', action='store',default=None, help='The location at which static files are stored')
parse.add_argument('--kvpairs', dest='kv', action='store',default=None, help='Key value pairs to make available to the target')
parse.add_argument('inputs', metavar='<input file>', nargs='+', action='store', help='xproto files to compile')

class XosGen:

    @staticmethod
    def init(args=None):

        if not args:
            args = parse.parse_args()

        args.quiet = False

        # convert output to absolute path
        if not os.path.isabs(args.output):
            args.output = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd() + '/' + args.output)
        if not os.path.isabs(args.target):
            args.target = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd() + '/' + args.target)

        inputs = []
        for fname in args.inputs:
            if not os.path.isabs(fname):
                inputs.append(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd() + '/' + fname))
            else:
                inputs.append(fname)
        args.inputs = inputs

        print args.output

        generator = XOSGenerator(args)
        generator.generate()
```

And here is the test:
    import unittest
    from mock import patch
    from xosgen.xosgen import XosGen

```
class Args:
    pass

class XOSGeneratorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Testing the CLI binding for the XOS Generative Toolchain
    """

    def test_generator(self):
        """
        [XOS-GenX] The CLI entry point should correctly parse params  
        """
        args = Args()
        args.inputs = ['../test.xproto']
        args.target = '../test.xtarget'
        args.output = '../out/dir'

        expected_args = Args()
        expected_args.inputs = ['/Users/teone/Sites/opencord/orchestration/xos/lib/test.xproto']
        expected_args.target = '/Users/teone/Sites/opencord/orchestration/xos/lib/test.xtarget'
        expected_args.output = '/Users/teone/Sites/opencord/orchestration/xos/lib/out/dir'

        with patch("xosgen.xosgen.XOSGenerator") as generator:
            XosGen.init(args)
            generator.assert_called_with(expected_args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

What I want to test is if the passed arguments were changed correctly, but my test is failing with:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: XOSGenerator(<test_cli.Args instance at 0x10abc29e0>)
Actual call: XOSGenerator(<test_cli.Args instance at 0x10abc2950>)
```

What would be the correct way to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling both

```
args = Args()
```

and

```
expected_args = Args()
```

you are assigning these two variables to two different objects, thus they fail the test case even though their attributes are the same.

To overcome this, you might want to specifically compare their attributes. Referring to [call_args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args),

```
with patch("xosgen.xosgen.XOSGenerator") as generator:
    XosGen.init(args)
    actual_args = generator.call_args[1]['args'] # if XOSGenerator takes in a keyword argument
    actual_args = generator.call_args[0][0] # otherwise, so comment one of these lines out
    assert actual_args.inputs == expected_args.inputs
    assert actual_args.target == expected_args.target
    assert actual_args.output == expected_args.output
```